Collision Avoidance ROS 3Laws Robotics Supervisor
Has anyone else tried a collision avoidance ROS from 3Laws Robotics? From my understanding, their software, Supervisor, can avoid collisions in 3D much better than it's counter parts that mostly do 2D avoidance. Let me know if you try it!
